# Howto anchor a Group of Elements to a specific TextFrame in InDesign CS5 javascript

Tags: javascript, scripting-language, adobe-indesign

I have written an importscript which places articles into a Indesign masterspread from a xml file. Every article will be placed into a new textframe. Every article can have multiple pictures with a caption. The picture and caption will be grouped while the import and should be anchored into the articles textframe.

The Script runs well importing the articles, and placing the paragraphs into the created textframe. Every picture and caption will also grouped correctly.

But at this point im stuck. I cant figure out howto anchor the group into the given textframe.

```
var frameBounds = ["10", "10", "300mm", "300mm"];
```

### Here i build the TextFrame

```
var article = xmlElements.placeIntoFrame(myDocument.pages.item(0), frameBounds);
```

### Importing Picture and Caption

```
var picture = xmlElements.itemByName("Image").placeIntoFrame(myDocument.pages.item(0),  ["10", "10", "150mm", "100mm"]);
var caption = xmlElements.itemByName("Caption").placeIntoFrame(myDocument.pages.item(0),  ["10", "10", "150mm", "100mm"];
```

### Grouping the Objects

#### Now want doing something like this.

This works:

```
var group =  app.activeDocument.groups.add([picture, signature], undefined,LocationOptions.AT_BEGINNING, article);
```

This doesnt work.

```
group.anchoredObjectSettings.anchoredPosition = AnchorPosition.ANCHORED;
```

Comment: If you found the answer to your question it belogns among the answers not in an edit of your question: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: I know. But if you just have 3 Reputation Points you cant do that in the first 8 hours.

Comment: The question was made yesterday, what's stopping you now? You can also delete your own question, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it by myself.

You have to insert:

```
group.anchoredObjectSettings.insertAnchoredObject(myElement.xmlElements[x].inser‌​tionPoints[0]);
```

May it is useful for someone else... Cheers.

Comment: Please, remove your answer from the question and post it here in your answer (cut and paste shouldn't be hard), then accept your own answer to let other people know that the issue here is solved.

Comment: I noticed that this works only for InDesign CS 5.5. The CS 5.0 DOM does not support group.anchoredObjectSettings.insertAnchoredObject. Is there a solution for CS5.0?